# Devise authentication - no confirmation after password recovery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, confirmation, password-recovery

I'm using Devise authentication gem with Rails.

How to display the message from devise.en.yml:

```
send_instructions: 'You will receive an email with instructions about how to reset your password in a few minutes'
```

after password recovery e-mail has been sent, instead of being redirected to site's root?

**Update:**

I've found an interesting piece of code in devise_controller.rb:

```
def successfully_sent?(resource)
  notice = if Devise.paranoid
    resource.errors.clear
    :send_paranoid_instructions
  elsif resource.errors.empty?
    :send_instructions
  end

  if notice
    set_flash_message :notice, notice if is_navigational_format?
    true
  end
end
```

Setting breakpoints shows that the right lines are being called, **:send_instructions** is assigned to **notice** , set_flash_message is called, but I cannot see the result of all this because I am immediately redirected to root path.

Comment: check if flash[:notice] was assighned + do u have block that renders flash messages + look at logs maybe u have double redirection

Comment: I have flash[:notice] block, but have no idea where the additional redirection may be hidden.

Comment: add did u checked that flash[:notice] was assighned?

Comment: yes, I have the condition there. BTW: how it can prevent redirecting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the source code for devise's PasswordsController: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb#L42

You'll have to create a PasswordsController in your app that inherits from Devise::PasswordsController, implement only the after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name) method and when setting the routes tell devise to use your controller

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  protected
  def after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
    #return your path
  end
end
```

in routes

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :passwords => "passwords" }
```

Comment: I have looked into resources - there is "send_instructions" string, which is never shown, but if it is there, there sould be a functionality which shows it. Today, while experimenting with controllers, I have unintentionally got this message, but do not know how.

Comment: Probably that's another question to ask. Most probably when you redirect to the path in after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for that path redirects to another page and the flash message is lost. Look through the log/development.log