# Devise authentication - what is the standard behaviour of this gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Devise authentication - what is the default behaviour of this gem?

I mean:

Should the user be redirected to site's root after password reset confirmation has been sent so, that I even do not see confirmation message, or, if it happens, it means some problems in my application?

Comment: Do you have problems with that? Is something broken?

Comment: I do not know how it should work, so I do not know whether something is wrong or not or whether I have done something in my application that prevents Devise from functioning properly. P.S. how it behaves now, I've described in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default it redirectes to new_session_path on successfull sent
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb

Comment: Can you look here? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658004/devise-authentication-no-confirmation-after-password-recovery

Answer (score 0):

Do you have put in the settings for email delivery​​?
if not so no email can be send

if you have do that after a forget PW request you get a email with a link
so you can reset the PW and you get redirect to root